# Get result from multiple array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$row_properties = array(
     "Header 1"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"colors"=>array(100,220,255)),
     "Header 2"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"colors"=>array(100,220,255)),
     "Header 3"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"colors"=>array(100,220,255)),
);
```

I try to get the `widths` and `algins` `colors` as array like this

```
$widths = array(20,20,20);
$aligns  = array("C","C","C")
$colors  array(array(100,220,255),array(100,220,255),array(100,220,255));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$widths = array();
$aligns = array();
$colors = array();

foreach($row_properties as $property) {
    $widths[] = $property['width'];
    $aligns[] = $property['align'];
    $colors[] = $property['colors'];
}
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$widths = $aligns = $colors = array();
foreach ($row_properties as $prop) {
  $widths[] = $prop['width'];
  $aligns[] = $prop['align'];
  $colors[] = $prop['color'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$widths = array();
$aligns  = array();
foreach($row_properties as $row){
   $widths[] = $row['width'];
   $aligns[] = $row['align'];
}
```